# regular expressions - finding price

Tags: php, regex

I am working on a regular expression that would grab the price in different format as I don't know in which format I am going to get the string so I am trying to cover as many variation as possible

Here is what I came up with

```
\$\s*?(\d+\.?\d*?)+|usd\s*?(\d+\.?\d*?)+|(\d+\.?\d*?)\s*?usd+|(\d+\.?\d*?)\s*?dollars?+|dollars?\s*?(\d+\.?\d*?)+|(\d+\.?\d*?)\s*?bucks?+|bucks?\s*?(\d+\.?\d*?)+
```

I've tried the above with several examples and it didn't fail so far.

anyone can think of a better way to achieve that ?

Comment: How about you included a sample of what inputs you expect?

Comment: input is random completely so i cannot give a specific example

Comment: Then the only thing you can do is to think of what case you want to capture and ignore the rare cases .

Comment: input is random completely so i cannot give a specific example.  Then give lots of examples!  Also, please read this article about the value of test data.  It's not about your problem, but hopefully you will get the idea of the importance of starting with the data, not the code. http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Web_Languages-Standards/PHP/A_7830-A-Quick-Tour-of-Test-Driven-Development.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real answer here is going to be achieved through **normalization** of the data.  Start by removing every character except digits, the dot, and (if you expect negative values) the hyphen.  Then you will have a character string that can be used as a number.  When you have some test data available, try normalization first before you try to write regular expressions.  Not only will the code be easier to write, but it will run faster, too!

Answer (score 0):

I would advise using seperate expressions for each variation, and testing them in sequence (most likely ones first), applying the chain of responibility pattern.

The advantage is maintainability. When you need to support a new variation (considering you don't know all possible cariations beforehand) it'll simply be a matter of adding another member to the chain, rather than fiddling with the arcane complexities of what you have built now.